# Guardar datos en un ArrayList desde un metodo de interfaz?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, interface

A ver como explico mi pregunta, porque me parece que acabare poniendo gran parte del código (disculparme), acabo de empezar con las interfaces, es la primera vez que hago un código con ellas, me han explicado lo básico, básico y me veo en la situación que debo hacer un ejercicio de un teatro en el que debo hacer un menú para vender entradas, consultarlas y consultar por zona vendida.

He creado dos interfaces:

**1.-Espectador:**

```
public interface Espectador  {

    public abstract double normal();
    public abstract double abonat();
    public abstract double reduit();
}
```

**2.-Zona:**

```
public interface Zona {
    public abstract int principal();
    public abstract int palc();
    public abstract int central();
    public abstract int lateral();
}
```

A partir de aqui he creado la **clase Entrada** que implementa ambas interfaces:

```
public class Entrada implements Zona,Espectador{

    //variables
    private int id;
    private static int identificadorgeneral = 0;
    private String nom;
    private int zona;
    private double tipus;
    private int localitats;

    //constructor
    public Entrada( String nom,int zona,double tipus) {
        this.id =identificadorgeneral;
           identificadorgeneral++;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.zona = zona;
        this.tipus = tipus;
    }

    //getters y setters
    public double getTipus() {
        return tipus;
    }


    public void setTipus(double tipus) {
        this.tipus = tipus;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }


    public int getZona() {
        return zona;
    }


    public void setZona(int zona) {
        this.zona = zona;
    }

    public int obtenerIdentificador() {
        return getId();
    }

    //intefaces
    @Override
    public double normal() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return 25;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return 70;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return 20;
        }
        else {
            return 15.5;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public double abonat() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return 17.5;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return 40;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return 14;
        }
        else {
            return 10;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public double reduit() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return (15/100)*25;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return (15/100)*70;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return (15/100)*20;
        }
        else {
            return (15/100)*15.5;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int principal() {
        return 200;
    }


    @Override
    public int palc() {
        return 40;
    }


    @Override
    public int central() {
        return 400;
    }


    @Override
    public int lateral() {
        return 100;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entrada Numero" + id + ", nom=" + nom + ", zona=" + zona + ", tipus=" + tipus;
    }   
}
```

He creado los métodos, según he visto conveniente, aunque no se si correctamente, deseo que las zonas devuelvan la cantidad de butacas vacías y los espectadores devuelvan el tipo de tarifa según precio.

Esta de abajo es mi **clase Main** donde tengo el método vender() ,aquí viene el problema, deseo que se añadan según la opción del menú un método de cada interfaz no se si esto es correcto tal vez no se muy bien como hacer que si elijo cada opción se coloque lo que deseo en el arraylist.

*Trozo del código donde tengo el problema:*

```
public static void vender() {

        String nom;
        int respuestaZona;
        int respuestaTipo;

        do {
            System.out.println("=*=*=*= Vender entradas =*=*=*=");

            System.out.println("Cual es su nombre?");
            nom = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Que zona desea comprar?\n1.-Principal\n2.-Palc\n3.-Central"
                    + "\n4.-Lateral\n5.-Salir");
            respuestaZona = lector.nextInt();

            lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

            switch(respuestaZona){
            case 1:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).principal(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).principal(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).principal(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).palc(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).palc(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).palc(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 3:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).central(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).central(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ((Zona) listaEntrada).central(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).lateral(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).lateral(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).lateral(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
                    break;
                }               
                break;
            }

        }while(respuestaZona !=4); 
        System.out.println("Gracias por su compra!");
    }
```

Sinceramente he ido probando sin saber exactamente si eso era correcto

```
listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).lateral(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
```

al llegar al punto en que se guarda en el add me da un **error por consola**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class Act5.Zona (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Act5.Zona is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Act5.Main.vender(Main.java:66) //la linea de codigo donde se guarda el primer arrayList
    at Act5.Main.main(Main.java:22) //la linea de codigo donde lanzo este metodo
```

Que estoy haciendo mal? como podría insertar los datos en el arrayList como he pensado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Estas intentando hacer un **casteo**, tienes una lista y a dicha lista intentas volverla un objeto de Zona o Espectador, esto no es posible.*

*Por otro lado veo que haz creado 2 interfaces y según analizo tu código, realmente necesitas una interfaz. tu **do while** solo finaliza si al elegir la zona selecciono la opción 4, de lo contrario estará repitiendo el proceso. te veo muy confundido, pero te replicaré un poco como deberías tener la interfaz y como hacer uso de ella, eso si. para que puedas comprender; solo he realizado dichos ajustes, pero a tu código aun le falta.*

Este sería el ejemplo de la interfaz:

```js
public interface EntradaInterfaz {

 // Zona
 public int principal();
    public int palc();
    public int central();
    public int lateral();
 
    // Espectador
    public double normal();
    public double abonat();
    public double reduit();
}
```

Ahora la Clase Entrada:

```js
package stackoverflow;

public class Entrada implements EntradaInterfaz {

    //variables
    private int id;
    private static int identificadorgeneral = 0;
    private String nom;
    private int zona;
    private double tipus;
    private int localitats;
    
    public Entrada() {
     
    }

    //constructor
    public Entrada( String nom,int zona,double tipus) {
        this.id =identificadorgeneral;
           identificadorgeneral++;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.zona = zona;
        this.tipus = tipus;
    }

    //getters y setters
    public double getTipus() {
        return tipus;
    }


    public void setTipus(double tipus) {
        this.tipus = tipus;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }


    public int getZona() {
        return zona;
    }


    public void setZona(int zona) {
        this.zona = zona;
    }

    public int obtenerIdentificador() {
        return getId();
    }

    //intefaces
    @Override
    public double normal() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return 25;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return 70;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return 20;
        }
        else {
            return 15.5;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public double abonat() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return 17.5;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return 40;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return 14;
        }
        else {
            return 10;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public double reduit() {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return (15/100)*25;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return (15/100)*70;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return (15/100)*20;
        }
        else {
            return (15/100)*15.5;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int principal() {
        return 200;
    }


    @Override
    public int palc() {
        return 40;
    }


    @Override
    public int central() {
        return 400;
    }


    @Override
    public int lateral() {
        return 100;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entrada Numero" + id + ", nom=" + nom + ", zona=" + zona + ", tipus=" + tipus;
    }   
}
```

```js
public class StackOverFlow {
 
 private static List<Object> listaEntrada = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   vender();
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 public static void vender() {
  Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nom;
        int respuestaZona;
        int respuestaTipo;
        EntradaInterfaz entrada = new Entrada();

        do {
            System.out.println("=*=*=*= Vender entradas =*=*=*=");

            System.out.println("Cual es su nombre?");
            nom = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Que zona desea comprar?\n1.-Principal\n2.-Palc\n3.-Central"
                    + "\n4.-Lateral\n5.-Salir");
            respuestaZona = lector.nextInt();

            lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

            switch(respuestaZona){
            case 1:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.principal(), entrada.normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.principal(), entrada.abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.principal(), entrada.reduit()));
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.palc(), entrada.normal()));
                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.palc(), entrada.abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.palc(), entrada.reduit()));
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 3:

                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.central(), entrada.normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.central(), entrada.abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.central(), entrada.reduit()));
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
                respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

                lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

                switch(respuestaTipo){
                case 1:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.lateral(), entrada.normal()));

                    break;
                case 2:

                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.lateral(), entrada.abonat()));
                    break;
                case 3:


                    listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, entrada.lateral(), entrada.reduit()));
                    break;
                }               
                break;
            }

        }while(respuestaZona !=4); 
        System.out.println("Gracias por su compra!");
        lector.close();
    }
}
```

**Aun tienes cosas por mejorar para que el código funcione como esperas.**

*Una interfaz en Java es una colección de métodos abstractos y propiedades constantes. En las interfaces se especifica qué se debe hacer pero no su implementación. Serán las clases que implementen estas interfaces las que describen la lógica del comportamiento de los métodos*. [interfaz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_(Java))

Answer (score 0):

> > Sinceramente he ido probando sin saber exactamente si eso era correcto:

```java
listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom,((Zona) listaEntrada).lateral(), ((Espectador) listaEntrada).reduit()));
```

Esta línea de código:

```java
((Zona)listaEntrada).lateral()
```

Le dice al compilador que la clase `ArrayList` (asumiendo que la variable `listaEntrada` es de tipo `ArrayList`) si implementa la interfaz `Zona` y que la clase está sobrescribiendo todos los métodos que tenga dicha interfaz.

Sin embargo, es mentira, la clase `ArrayList` en ningún momento implementa la interfaz `Zona`, por lo tanto, al momento de ejecutar el programa, la `JVM` dará una excepción porque el método `lateral()` no existe en la clase `ArrayList`.

**(1.) Una posible solución** es crear un constructor sin parámetros en la clase `Entrada`:

```java
public class Entrada implements Zona,Espectador{

    //variables
    private int id;
    private static int identificadorgeneral = 0;
    private String nom;
    private int zona;
    private double tipus;
    private int localitats;
    //Constructor sin parámetros
    public Entrada()
    {

    }

    //constructor
    public Entrada( String nom,int zona,double tipus) {
        this.id =identificadorgeneral;
           identificadorgeneral++;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.zona = zona;
        this.tipus = tipus;
    }
    //el resto del código
    //.....
}
```

Y posteriormente creas un objeto de tipo `Entrada` al principio del método `vender()`:

```java
public static void vender() {

        //Creamos el objeto
        Entrada ent = new Entrada();
        String nom;
        int respuestaZona;
        int respuestaTipo;
     //el resto del código...

}
```

Luego nos vamos a la línea del código donde habías hecho el casting de forma errónea y lo reemplazamos por esta sentencia:

```java
listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, ent.lateral(), ent.reduit()));
```

Así mismo haces con el resto del código que tenga un casting erróneo.

**Recomendaciones:**

**1.** Veo el código muy redundante. Podríamos crear un método llamado `agregarEntrada`, en la cual tenga tres parámetros:

- `int zona`: Para saber el tipo de zona (`principal`, `central`, `lateral`).
- `Entrada ent`: Recibe la referencia del objeto de tipo `Entrada`. Servirá expresamente para invocar a los métodos: `normal()`, `abonat`, `reduit`.
- `String nom`: Recibe la referencia del objeto de tipo `String`, que servirá para saber cual es el nombre de la zona.

Implementación del método (debería ir en la clase `Main`):

```java
public static void agregarEntrada(int zona, Entrada ent, String nom)
{
    int respuestaTipo;
    System.out.println("Tipo de precio\n1.-Normal\n2.-Abonado\n3.-Reducido");
    respuestaTipo = lector.nextInt();

    lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

    switch(respuestaTipo)
    {
    case 1:
        listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, zona, ent.normal()));
        break;
    case 2:
        listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, zona, ent.abonat()));
        break;
    case 3:
        listaEntrada.add(new Entrada(nom, zona, ent.reduit()));
        break;
    }
}
```

Y luego lo invocamos de esta manera:

```java
public static void vender() {

        String nom;
        int respuestaZona;
        Entrada ent = new Entrada();
        do {
            System.out.println("=*=*=*= Vender entradas =*=*=*=");

            System.out.println("Cual es su nombre?");
            nom = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Que zona desea comprar?\n1.-Principal\n2.-Palc\n3.-Central"
                    + "\n4.-Lateral\n5.-Salir");
            respuestaZona = lector.nextInt();

            lector.nextLine();//limpia el bufer del teclado

            switch(respuestaZona){
            case 1:
                agregarEntrada(ent.principal(), ent, nom);
                break;
            case 2:
                agregarEntrada(ent.palc(), ent, nom);
                break;
            case 3:
                agregarEntrada(ent.central(), ent, nom);
                break;
            case 4:
                agregarEntrada(ent.lateral(), ent, nom);            
                break;
            }
        }while(respuestaZona !=4); 
        System.out.println("Gracias por su compra!");
    }
```

**2.** Si te das cuenta, los métodos: `normal()`, `abonat()`, `reduit()` tienen el mismo código. Por lo tanto, podríamos crear un método denominado `getPrecio()` en la cual tenga el código necesario para reutilizarlo en los tres métodos.

Implementación del método (se lo debe agregar en la clase `Entrada`):

```java
    public double getPrecio(double precio_principal, double precio_palc, double precio_central, double precio_lateral)
    {
        if(getZona()==principal()) {
            return precio_principal;
        }
        if(getZona()==palc()) {
            return precio_palc;
        }
        if(getZona()==central()) {
            return precio_central;
        }
        else {
            return precio_lateral;
        }
    }
```

Para invocarlo se lo haría de esta forma:

```java
    @Override
    public double normal() {
        return getPrecio(25, 70, 20, 15.5);
    }


    @Override
    public double abonat() {
        return getPrecio(17.5, 40, 14, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public double reduit() {
        return getPrecio((15/100)*25, (15/100)*70, (15/100)*20, (15/100)*15.5);
    }
```